# How to install and use Wt (web GUI library) in WSL

Tags: wsl-2, wt

I'm using WSL2 (Debian) on Windows 10.

How can I install and use Wt library?

When I try to use the recommended command on the Wt website

```
$ sudo apt-get install witty witty-dev witty-doc witty-dbg witty-examples
```

I get this:

```
E: Unable to locate package witty
E: Unable to locate package witty-dev
E: Unable to locate package witty-doc
E: Unable to locate package witty-dbg
E: Unable to locate package witty-examples
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Downloads

- Wt from https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt (e.g. wt-4.5.0.tar.gz)
- Boost from https://www.boost.org/users/download/ (e.g. boost_1_75_0.tar.gz)

#### Required Packages

```
$ sudo apt -y install g++ cmake
```

#### Install Boost Library

```
$ tar xvfz boost_1_75_0.tar.gz
$ cd boost_1_75_0
$ ./bootstrap.sh
$ sudo ./b2 install
```

The header files and the libraries are in `/usr/local/include/boost` and  `/usr/local/lib`, respectively.

```
$ sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib    # Update ldconfig cache
```

#### Install Wt Library

```
$ tar xvfz wt-4.5.0.tar.gz
$ cd wt-4.5.0
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ../
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ make -C examples   # optional
```

#### Try It

(examples required)

```
$ cd examples/hello/
$ ln -s ../../../resources/
$ ./hello.wt --docroot . --http-listen 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Open the browser and browse to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ .

Comment: I had to run `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib` again after the Wt install, else I get error like `libwthttp.so.4.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when compiling the hello example from the [tutorial](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/wt.html)